# graphql-cli output does not produce @unique

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am working on generating a data model for Prisma server by using `graphql-cli`. However, `graphql-cli` keep producing id propery without `@unique` and  I get this error when I deploy it to prisma demo server.

> The field `id` is reserved and has to have the format: id: ID! @unique.

So my question is **how can I make graph-cli generate @unique?**

My prisma.graphql(aka datamodel.graphql) has

```
type Comment implements Node {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  userIdCommenBy: String!
  videoId: String!
  createdTime: String!
}
```

this type which should be

```
type Comment implements Node {
  id: ID! @unique
  content: String!
  userIdCommenBy: String!
  videoId: String!
  createdTime: String!
}
```

schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  feeds: [Video]
  users: [User]
  user: User
  videos: [Video]
  video: Video
  comments: [Comment]
  comment: Comment
  questions: [Question]
  question: Question
}

type Mutation {
  addUser(id: ID, firstName: String, lastName: String, companyId: String): User
  addComment(id: ID, content: String, userIdCommenBy: String): Comment
  addQuestion(id: ID, title: String, userIdAsekedBy: String, isAnonymous: String): Question
}

type User {
  id: ID
  email: String
  password: String
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  companyId: String
  createdTime: String
}

type Video {
  id: ID
  questionId: String
  imgUrl: String
  videoUrl: String
  views: Int
  likes: Int
  isPrivate: Boolean
  comments: [Comment]
  createdTime: String
}

type Comment {
  id: ID
  content: String
  userIdCommenBy: String
  videoId: String
  createdTime: String
}

type Question {
  id: ID
  title: String
  userIdAsekedBy: String
  isAnonymous: Boolean
  countSkipped: Int
  views: Int
  createdTime: String
}

type Notification {
  isRead: Boolean
  isHidden: Boolean
  senderId: String
  recipientId: String
  typeOfNotification: String
  createdTime: String
}
```

.graphqlconfig.yml

```
projects:
    app:
        schemPath: src/schema.graphql
        extensions:
            endpoints:
            default: ${env:API_ENDPOINT}
    prisma:
        schemaPath: src/prisma/prisma.graphql
        extensions:
            prisma: src/prisma/prisma.yml
```

The command I run
`graphql get-schema --project prisma --dotenv .env.dev`

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the **data model** (typically called `datamodel.graphql`) with the **Prisma database schema** (typically called `prisma.graphql`).

The data model is used by Prisma to automatically generate the Prisma database schema:

[image]

The `@unique` directive is specific to Prisma. Therefore you can only use it inside your data model. The Prisma database schema is not supposed to have this directive any more.

I just created a small gist to explain the difference between the two in more detail: https://gist.github.com/nikolasburk/eef24cd0d907b4a3e073723054cf847d

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now, I clearly understand it. Basically, I needed datamodel.graphql (for Prisma database) and schema.graphql (for my graphql server). It is working now. I appreciate it!